# Can i delete microsoft visual c++

Tags: windows-10, window, microsoft

My computer's Programs and Features is full of Microsoft redistributables, but different versions.

How would I know that which redistributables are not in use so
I can delete them, or can install all redistributables
from 2005 to 2015 in one install.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We like just one question per question, so I've edited out your second. See https://www.easeus.com/backup-recovery/this-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly.html

Comment: "How would I know that which redistributables are not in use" - As the system Administrator you would analysis which programs you have installed and which versions of the Visual C++ Redistributable is required for each of those applications.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal to have many versions of the Microsoft runtime.

Each is installed by some program that requires it, that without it wouldn't
work. Unfortunately, there is no way to know which program installed which
runtime.

My advice is to leave these runtimes in place - they are not that costly
as regarding disk space. If you uninstall one runtime, you might find
out much later that some program will not work any more.